# OpenVPN and systemd-resolved: DNS does not resolve VPN internal names

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn, systemd

I have a VPN set up on some virtual machines using OpenVPN. One of the VMs is running dnsmasq to provide a basic DNS for inside the network. My client is running Ubuntu, which now more or less forces systemd-resolved. I am finding that although it claims to have configured DNS, I can't actually do an nslookup or dig on hostnames inside the VPN. I can ping them by IP, but not by name.

Let's dive into configuration files.

OpenVPN server conf:

```
mode server
local 192.168.50.101
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/server/ssl/ca.pem
cert /etc/openvpn/server/ssl/cert.pem
key /etc/openvpn/server/ssl/key.pem
dh /etc/openvpn/server/ssl/dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.99.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.99.0.1"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
comp-lzo
push "comp-lzo yes"
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 6
mute 20
```

Client conf:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 192.168.50.101 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca REDACTED
cert REDACTED
key REDACTED
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
mute 20
ping-restart 30
script-security 2
setenv PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre
```

I have installed https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved, as seems to be recommended. It does, in fact, update the DNS settings as can be shown by the systemd-resolved logs (`Switching to DNS server 10.99.0.1 for interface tun0.`) and `--status` output:

```
Link 26 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.99.0.1
```

`/etc/resolve.conf` points to 127.0.0.53, as is the default for using systemd-resolved.

I've tried using NetworkManager's built-in OpenVPN connection, and it neither fixes the DNS issue, nor even sets up routes correctly (so I can't even ping or connect by IP).

Just a few other things that people will probably ask about:

- This setup works for my coworkers on Macs, using Viscosity. It's only Ubuntu/Linux that's failing here on the client side.
- Firewall on OpenVPN server allows port 53 and I can verify with telnet.
- If I set up `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to my VPN's DNS server (on 10.99.0.1), then DNS resolution works fine. However, resolv.conf is managed by either systemd-resolved or NetworkManager via resolvconf and I'd like to keep those if possible so as not to upset the Ubuntu apple cart.

Comment: Prolly not an OpenVPN problem. I just used bind as dns so far. I guess you did not allow other ips to lookup some other addresses (default in bind) than the ones you setup. Also you may need to create zone files for those domains or configure the dns as cache server to lookup.

Comment: @Tom-OliverHeidel: the DNS can work. If I, for example, put my DNS server in as the only entry in /etc/resolv.conf, it works fine. Since that DNS is also used internally in the private network for DNS to the outside world, it would not block sites like Google from being resolved. The problem is on how systemd-resolved or NetworkManager is handling it.

Comment: Related bug reports: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5755 https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6076 https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7182 and potentially useful script: https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved

Answer (score 1):

First, test connect from console:

```
sudo openvpn --verb 1 --config /path_to_conf/config.ovpn
```

If you have this error:

> /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a
> symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

then fix **/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc**

before

```
DYNAMICRSLVCNFFILE="/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf"
```

after

```
#DYNAMICRSLVCNFFILE="/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf"
DYNAMICRSLVCNFFILE="/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf"
```

Second, add option to openvpn server config.

```
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME"
```

**Update.** DNS requests only via VPN. Search UUID vpn connection

```
nmcli c show

nmcli c modify <UUID vpn connection> ipv4.dns-priority -1
```

After this command reconnect vpn. Now all dns request go to vpn

Comment: this is not instructive, just giving some commands doesn't help the ones who come after

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by installing the `update-systemd-resolved` package on Ubuntu (you don't mention what OS are you using, I'm sure there are equivalent packages in other distros). And adding this to the openvpn client config file:

```
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
```

When I connect with the above settings added I see this in the openvpn log:

```
Wed Feb 24 13:13:20 2021 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Wed Feb 24 13:13:20 2021 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.6.200.2/24 broadcast 10.6.200.255
Wed Feb 24 13:13:20 2021 /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved tun0 1500 1553 10.6.200.2 255.255.255.0 init
<14>Feb 24 13:13:20 update-systemd-resolved: Link 'tun0' coming up
<14>Feb 24 13:13:20 update-systemd-resolved: Adding IPv4 DNS Server 10.6.0.9
<14>Feb 24 13:13:20 update-systemd-resolved: Setting DNS Domain example.com
<14>Feb 24 13:13:20 update-systemd-resolved: Setting DNS Domain example.com
<14>Feb 24 13:13:20 update-systemd-resolved: SetLinkDNS(15 1 2 4 10 6 0 9)
<14>Feb 24 13:13:20 update-systemd-resolved: SetLinkDomains(15 1 example.com false)
```

And running `resolvectl` shows me I'm using the correct DNS Servers and DNS Domain for the `tun0` link.

The source for this script is at https://salsa.debian.org/debian/openvpn-systemd-resolved/-/blob/master/update-systemd-resolved